# How to view remove subview?

Tags: swift, tableview, dismiss

```
let overlayView = UIView()

overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.35)

overlayView.frame = self.view.bounds

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0{ self.view.addSubview(overlayView) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "language", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Present Modally with second view controller send. @IBAction func close_click(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }  remove subview ?

Comment: overlayView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // this gets things done
overlayView.subviews.map({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // this returns modified array

Comment: @DhavalRaval Problem second view controller click buton dismiss one view controller subview remove?

Comment: i dont understand exactly

Comment: @DhavalRaval there is 2 view controller. 1. view controller   self.view.addSubview(overlayView)  2.view controller removeSubview how to

Comment: @DhavalRaval There are 2 view controllers. I can add the overlay in the 1st view controller. When I click the "dismiss" button in the 2nd view controller, I want overlay to be hidden. How can I make this possible?

Comment: @EnesOzel you seem to be loading a view, then loading another viewController over the top of it.  Is second view controller not full screen and you want to use the overlay view to blur the first view controller?

Comment: @flanker Exactly

Answer (score 0):

To do what you ask you could have the overlay view as an optional, class level property, and try to remove it when the view appears

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
  var overlayView: UIView?


override func viewDidAppear() {
  super.viewDidAppear()
  overlayView?.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

Or you could use a protocol / delegate pattern to inform VC1 that VC2 was bring removed and use that method to remove the overlayView.   This is a cleaner solution.

However if you're doing whatever I think you are tyring to do (see my comment) I think there is a better approach - handle it all in the second view controller.  Make the main view of second view controller do the masking by setting it's alpha, then add a container view to the centre of that view and add all your content/functionality into that container view.  This way when you dismiss the second  the blur layer will go with it.

Comment: class VC1: UIViewController { var overlayView: UIView? }

class VC2:  UIViewController {  overlayView?.removeFromSuperView() }


How to remove ?

Comment: don't understand your question?

Comment: There's three possible ways you can do it in the answer above!  The easiest is to make the overlay view optional and then put `overlayView?.removeFromSuperView()` in your `viewWillAppear()`